# Toggle-switch library + Bootstrap submenu = how to stop propagation?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm talking about - http://jsfiddle.net/NJc5b/ - I need the submenu to don't close when I change the switch value. As you see `e.stopPropagation();` does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/NJc5b/2/

```
$('.dropdown-menu').sortable();
$(document).on('click', '.switch-toggle *', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('wtf');
});
```

Simply changing your label to a * does the job. You need to stop propagation from all child elements of the switch, without interfering with the propagation of other submenu items.

Comment: Yeah, figured it out by myself, could you please help me with next issue - http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/NJc5b/3/ - why width of the switch is not involved in width of submenu?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NJc5b/5/ You need to set a width for the `.switch-toggle`, otherwise the absolutely positioned element won't be able to use it to properly extend the width of the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, selector 'li *' solves the case. http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/NJc5b/1/

```
$(document).on('click', 'li *', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('wtf');
});
```